# Make citation on Microsoft Word clickable when using Mendeley Cite

Tags: microsoft-word, mendeley

I am using Microsoft Word 2016 and the [Mendeley Cite](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/mendeley-cite) plugin to manage my references. I click add reference, I select a reference from the list and it adds it properly. I also added a bibliography at the end of my document.

However, when I click on a reference in my document, I want to jump to the appropriate location in the document's bibliography section.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of [these macros](https://github.com/mabentwickeltsich/MendeleyMacros) to achieve that for IEEE and APA styles.